# Error computing Robust Standard errors in Panel regression model (plm,R)

Tags: r, standard-error, robust, plm

I am using the plm library to run fixed effect regressions and the sandwich,lmtest libraries to compute robust standard errors.  I have no problem running the regressions, but in some instances when I go to compute the standard errors I get the following error:

```
library(plm)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

fe_reg <- plm(y ~ x + I(x^2)+factor(date), data=reg_data, index=c("id","date"), model="within")
coeftest(fe_reg, vcov.=vcovHC(fe_reg, type="HC1"))

RRuntimeError: Error in solve.default(crossprod(demX))
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.84726e-25
```

I do not have any problems computing the coefficients or the "normal" standard errors (ie homoscedastic).  Also, I have no problem computing the robust standard errors when I omit the quadratic term:

```
fe_reg <- plm(y ~ x +factor(date), data=reg_data, index=c("id","date"), model="within")
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on?  If the design matrix were singular then the coefficients should not have been computed, so I don't understand where the issue is coming from when computing the standard errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, `plm` is not very verbose. I think it is possible to have a singular matrix but plm does not complain. `lm` is usually more verbose. So try

```
 lm_mod1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)+factor(date), data=reg_data)
 summary(lm_mod1)
```

`lm`will tell you in it's summary output if there is a problem calculating one coefficient (coefficient is `NA` in the table and there should be a note at the top of the output as well). **Edit**: The note at top of lm's summary output should be "Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)" in this case.

**Edit** There is another possibility why the coeftest is not working:
If your `model.matrix` contrains very large values as well as very small values, `solve` might not be able to solve the system of linear equations by computation in the `vcovHC` function. Thus, have a look at `model.matrix(y ~ x + I(x^2)+factor(date), data=reg_data)` if this is the case. If so, try rescaling some variables (e.g. multiply oder divide by 100 oder 1000 [also `log()` makes sense sometimes). Take care, the interpretation of the coefficients changes due to the change of scales!

Comment: The note at top of summary's output should be "Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)".

Comment: Yes, it is probable that there is a singularity, and while `plm()` and `summary()` work all right, `vcovHC()` would likely fail.

Comment: addendum: `plm`'s `vcovHC()` now (development version) handles singularities just like `plm()` and `summary()`: drop and continue, so the initial question should be resolved.

Comment: addendum 2: The official CRAN release (1.6-4) of plm now has that incorporated.